# warm up solutions for asp.net (mvc) sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I understand that the page load of asp.net (mvc 2.0ish) sites can suffer for many reasons after some idle time.

There are some free and commercial solutions that hit such sites in time intervals to prevent this.

Am I right in assuming that these solutions only help in speeding up the page load of the main/home page? If I am right are there also some solutions that crawl the dedicated site (potentially including form authenticated pages)?

Thanks.

PS: I use wild card mapping for my asp.net mvc apps. My server is a ms server 2003 with IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider precompiling the `Views` which makes a significant difference in startup time and has a similar effect to hitting every single page periodically, but without the hassle of actually doing so.

This is easy to accomplish using David Ebbo and Pranav Krishnamoorthy's excellent **Razor Generator** which can be installed via `NuGet`. Read a little about it here: http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/06/precompile-your-mvc-views-using.html and here is the Codeplex homepage: http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/documentation

Search `NuGet` for `RazorGenerator.Mvc`.

I have used this project successfully. It's great!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things,

**Application Pool Recycling**

In IIS there is Application Pool Recycling time according to which, App Pool is recycled after the specified time if it is idle. You can increase this time so that your App Pool is not recycled frequently.

- [Configure Application Pool Recycling](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1eee28e2-b319-4b4e-8267-a8c0aa0dcf36.mspx?mfr=true)
- [How to modify Application Pool Recycling Time](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/332088)

**Custom Solution**

You can easily write a custom solution which can hit your app periodically. For this you can use WebClient, HttpWebRequest classes. Its very easy to do this.

Hope this helps.